# Can I make vertices from multiple objects move a set distance along an axis automatically?

Tags: modeling, scripting

I have created a simple "matchbox" for my 3D Printer, and it has three parts: the box itself, a hole shape for a lid, and the actual box lid. If I want to change the size of the box, I need to manually move ~8 faces, (~25 vertices) to make one side of the box bigger or smaller. This seemed like something that would be easy to automate using scripts, but I wanted to see if it is actually possible to do this (and possibly find where I should start learning) first.

So, in short, I have 3 objects. I want to move a few of the sides on each object a select distance along a select axis to make the objects bigger or smaller. (I do not want to use the scale tool, because I want the distance between my lid and the box to remain constant) How do I go about this?